# Apple rejected my app because a link to a Privacy Policy is not listed

Tags: ios, appstore-approval

My app is a very simple custom keyboard, that does not collect any user data. The privacy policy that I came up with is:

"AppName does not have access to any of your data, nor does AppName collect any of your data."

Is this an acceptable privacy policy? Thanks.

Comment: I would add something relating to the fact that it would never change like

`AppName does not have access to any of your data, nor does or will AppName ever collect any of your data.`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it concerns the policies and procedures of app distribution services, rather than programming. Please refer to: [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic?‍](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165), [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?(https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that AppName *does* have access to user data.  Third-party keyboards have access to everything a user types.  I would say something like `AppName has not and will not use your data for anything other than services required for AppName to function.  AppName will not share, upload, or otherwise transmit your data to any servers, whether owned by CompanyName/DevName or owned by a third party.  AppName will never sell your data to any third parties.` or some variant of that.

Comment: Thanks! I will use this one.

Answer (score 0):

I would add something relating to the fact that it would never change like:

> AppName does not have access to any of your data, nor does or will AppName ever collect any of your data.

If they don't accept it again, email them and ask why.

Good Luck!